# Typescript autocomplete assumes homogenous values in generic arrays

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

When using generic for array parameters, typescript autocomplete assumes that all objects are homogeneous. Is there an explanation for such behaviour and/or a way to make autocomplete suggest melons?

```js
type Fruits = {apples: number, melons?: number}

const addToBasket = <T extends Fruits[]>(basket: T)=>{
  return basket
}

// melons are missing in autocomplete for the second object
addToBasket([{apples:1}, {apples:1 }])

// melons appear in autocomplete for second object
addToBasket([{apples:1, melons: 1}, {apples:1 }])
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=50&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbAM5QLxQN4EMxgA2EqAXFAHYIC2ARhHADRTUSED2FqA-OVXQwC+AKGEBjTqmBRcAE1kAVdgCFcqANYRpWADwKoEAB7AIFWenjI0AbQC6APgAUtNZuDkFASgz3swqFBwWghwFFAuGlrCIsIA9LGsHFwyQSxIqKhIFADmUFkyCMDsEtREWtAAZuxwUMAAFtCoEBJmUOy0AFbNwMJyiiquWo7WeATEZACMgsyjZZOCtp6i8YmSMgQQuDX5uIXF7KXEJr3ySqqRwMOz46QTzKtc5FMz+HO3UAueQA)

In the first call to `addToBasket` above, `melons` isn't suggested as a property. It does appear in the autocomplete, but only in the general list of identifiers in scope that might be relevant and it's a bit buried:

[image: screenshot showing autocomplete with all kinds of unrelated identifiers in it]

Notice how `Fruits` and `basket` and all sorts are in the list, and `melons` isn't identified as a property. In contrast, in the second call to `addBasket`, `melons` is suggested as a property:

[image: screenshot showing autocomplete with just "melons" listed and flagged as a property]

It's reported in [this TypeScript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43917) and perhaps related to [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37249).

Comment: Thanks! I found the actual issue on github could you please change it to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43917

The workaround I posted earlier is actually not actually solving the problem as it will behave similarly once you starting more than two properties.

Comment: Done -- but you can always use the "edit" link to edit your question. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NlpVlN) work for your use cases?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the code in the question to demonstrate the unmet needs.